# Spark serialization on object reference

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization

Dose Spark serialization generate object for every object reference?

I have a job that all rows referencing to one big object, actually because all are just object reference the overall data is not exceeds 1G. 
But while caching the bad thing happens ([the partition is too large to save](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6235) ).

The Java serialization [preserving object reference by id](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151055/what-happens-if-we-serialize-and-deserialize-two-objects-which-references-to-eac).
Is Spark the same or it reify (explode!) all reference? I can not find document about this but I think there should be.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a question you should be asking with regard to big objects, but is relevant for some cases involving small objects and reference equality.

For a large object, you should be using broadcast variables:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables